# JIRA python Library JiraError 400: Field 'summary' cannot be set

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I am trying to integrate Jira with Python using Rest API.

I am using the below mentioned code to create an issue in JIRA using Python. However I am encountering an error mentioned below.

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('Username,'API Token'), options={"server": "https://ProjectName.atlassian.net/"})

options={"server": "https://ProjectName.atlassian.net/"}

jira=JIRA(options)

test_case_data= {
    "project": {"id": "10000"},
    "summary": "test summary",
    "description": "test description",
    "issuetype": {'name': 'Task'},
}

jira.create_issue(fields=test_case_data)
```

Below is the error I am getting:

JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://ProjectName.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue
text: Field 'summary' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown., Field 'description' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.[image]

Comment: There's an extra comma after the last key, but this doesn't seem to be the real problem (rather a copy&paste&delete artefact).

Answer (score 0):

Was facing a similar issue today. Try using the full email address associated with the account as the username.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to create a Jira issue with the same account and with the exactly same input data? Is summary field really available?

Checkout [Atlassian REST API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-post) - they described various cases when server might return error 400. They also use REST API v3, you use v2 (but this shouldn't be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

In my Case it helps to make a request only with the type. I see that there are new Types created for the Project. You can found them by get api/projectTypes.
Try to let your other fields empty and then you got the message type is invalid.
Found the issuetypes for project and use that as id.